# GeoServer always returns cached data

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, javascript

I'm calling a tms service from service, and for some reason it looks like no matter what I do, it always gets cached data and is never aware of any modification from the database.

I've tried to delete browser cache, delete cache from GeoServer option, stop and start GeoServer, stop and start database and telling layer not to use cache but none of those things seem to work.

I'm using [this](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid) for Leaflet, instead of using what comes next, in case it had to do anything:

```
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.vectorgrid@latest/dist/Leaflet.VectorGrid.bundled.js"></script>
```

My tms url is:

```
var campground_geoserverlayer = 'data_nl:point';
// Creating the full vectorTile url
var campingURL = '/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/' + campground_geoserverlayer + '@EPSG%3A' + projection_epsg_no + '@pbf/{z}/{x}/{-y}.pbf';
```

I try to read data with this:

```
camping_vectorgrid.on('click', function(e) {
    displayBase64Image(e.layer.properties.naamnl,e,map);
       })
      .addTo(map
```

);

In e.layer.properties.naamnl there's always the first value used, changing naamnl to other database field doesn't help, it also always returns its initial value.

What could I do so cached data is not used if there's a new value in the database?

Comment: If you use this path `campingURL = '/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/'`if goes to GeoWebCache. Deleting the cache shoud remove the old tiles, though. If you use WMS service from `/geoserver/wms` instead there should be no problem with old tiles.

Comment: @user30184, can you put how the whole url would be? Doing var campingURL = '/geoserver/wms/' + campground_geoserverlayer + '@EPSG%3A' + projection_epsg_no + '@pbf/{z}/{x}/{-y}.pbf'; has the effect of directly not even making my point layer to appear.

Comment: WMS and TMS are different kind of services. Changing the url is not enough. Perhaps documentation helps https://leafletjs.com/examples/wms/wms.html. But it is also really possible to delete the old tiles. Try "truncate" seeding option from the GWC demo page. See https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/geowebcache/webadmin/demopage.html#gwc-webadmin-demo

Answer (score 1):

TMS is probably using GeoWebCache, you could try disabling it in Geoserver at the "Tile Caching" tab of the layer by setting the values to "-1"

[image]

Comment: sorry but it doesn't seem to work either.